# Identical and different object distribution among children

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

In how many ways can we distribute $12$ identical apples and $7$ distinguishable cookies among 5 children..?

My answer is $\binom{12+5-1}{12} \cdot 5^7$

Is it correct?

Explanation: Since there is no restriction to distribute the apples, I lined up the 12 apples and split them into 5 groups using the stars method and for the second one, It is only like assigning a cookie to each child.

What if it says, $7$ distinguishable cookies among $5$ children so that everyone gets at least one?

My answer is: $\binom{7}{5} * 5! * 5^2$
We give the kids $5$ cookies and they can be arranged in $5!$ ways, then we normally distribute the remaining cookies.

Am I missing anything? Are there any notes or something you would like to add up or advice?

Comment: For the second question, you still gave them apples?

Comment: No, I just did it separately, otherwise, I will have to multiply it by the way we distribute apples.

Comment: In your explanation for your correct answer to the first question, you meant to say that you split the apples into *five* groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution of first question is perfectly correct. You didn't miss anything.

For the second question:

Let $A_i$ be the set of all distributions in which $i-$th children don't get a cookie.

Then $|A_i| = 4^7$ for each $i$.

$|A_i\cap A_j|=3^7$ for each $i\ne j$

$|A_i\cap A_j\cap A_k|=2^7$ for each $i\ne j\ne k\ne i$

$|A_i\cap A_j\cap A_k\cap A_l|=1$ for all pairvise different $i,j,k,l$

Now we are interested in
  $$\Big| \bigcap_{i=1}^n \overline A_i\Big| = \Big|\; \overline{\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i}\;\Big|
= 5^7-\Big|\; \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\;\Big|
$$We have by PIE:
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \Big|\; \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\;\Big| &=& \sum_{i=1}^n  \Big|\; A_i\ \Big| - \sum_{i=1}^n  \Big|\;A_i\cap A_j\ \Big|+...\\
&=& 5\cdot 4^7-10\cdot 3^7+10\cdot 2^7-5+0=\\
\end{eqnarray*}

So the finaly answer is $5^7-5\cdot 4^7+10\cdot 3^7-5\cdot 2^7+1$.

Comment: Thanks so much for that ;)